# Loop through div children and bold specific text not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a suggestion dropdown under an input field and I am trying to make the text in the suggestion divs bold for the portion that matches what is currently in the input field.

e.g

input: AB
dropdown: **AB**CDE

My current code doesn't seem to be replacing the div content with the span

JS:

```
BoldMatchedText(inputToMatch:string){
    var outerDiv = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    if(outerDiv != null){
        var subDiv = outerDiv.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (var i = 0; i < subDiv.length; i++){
            subDiv[i].innerHTML.replace(inputToMatch, "<span id=\"strong\">" + inputToMatch + "</span>");
        }
    }
}
```

html:

```
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="dropdown-input">
            <div id="dropdown">
                <div class="reg-list-item">{{reg1}}</div>
                <div class="reg-list-item">{{reg2}}</div>
                <div class="reg-list-item">{{reg3}}</div>
                <div class="reg-list-item">{{reg4}}</div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of calling the function `replace`.

```
subDiv[i].innerHTML = subDiv[i].innerHTML.replace(inputToMatch, "<span id=\"strong\">" + inputToMatch + "</span>");
```

```js
function BoldMatchedText(inputToMatch) {
  var outerDiv = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  if (outerDiv != null) {
    var subDiv = outerDiv.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < subDiv.length; i++) {
      subDiv[i].innerHTML = subDiv[i].innerHTML.replace(inputToMatch, "<span id=\"strong\">" + inputToMatch + "</span>");
    }
  }
}

BoldMatchedText('Go');
```

```css
#strong {
  font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="dropdown-input">
  <div id="dropdown">
    <div class="reg-list-item">Ele</div>
    <div class="reg-list-item">Gomez</div>
    <div class="reg-list-item">Rod</div>
    <div class="reg-list-item">Enr</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this working sample with a benchmark. Compared with the previous answer.

```js
function BoldMatchedText1(inputToMatch) {
  var outerDiv = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  if (outerDiv != null) {
    var subDiv = outerDiv.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < subDiv.length; i++) {
      subDiv[i].innerHTML = subDiv[i].innerHTML.replace(inputToMatch, "<span id=\"strong\">" + inputToMatch + "</span>");
    }
  }
}

function BoldMatchedText2(inputToMatch) {
  var outerDiv = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  if(outerDiv !== null) {
    // Use `getElementsByClassName` instead using `getElementsByTagName('div')` JS will traverse your entire HTML file and look for all div tags, may take a little longer if you have a lot
    var items = outerDiv.getElementsByClassName("reg-list-item");
    // Getting the iteration length before the loop will give you performance benefit since items.length will not be checked per iteration
    var len = items.length;
    // Using while loop evaluating only if len is any positive number (true) except 0 (false) with reverse iteration making it faster
    while(len--) {
      var item = items[len].innerHTML;
      // ONLY replace the text that contains the `inputToMatch`
      if(item.indexOf(inputToMatch) !== -1) {
        items[len].innerHTML = item.replace(inputToMatch, "<span id=\"strong\">" + inputToMatch + "</span>");
      }
    }
  }
}

console.time('filter1');
BoldMatchedText1('Gom');
console.timeEnd('filter1');

console.time('filter2');
BoldMatchedText2('Gom');
console.timeEnd('filter2');
```

```css
#strong {
  font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="dropdown-input">
  <div id="dropdown">
    <div class="reg-list-item">Ele</div>
    <div class="reg-list-item">Gomez</div>
    <div class="reg-list-item">Rod</div>
    <div class="reg-list-item">Enr</div>
  </div>
</form>
```